# How to simply explode (d.m.Y H:i) using Php

Tags: php, date, time

I will use the easiest way to explode (day,month,year,hour,minute)  from a date string like this one `"2014-08-30T15:30:00"`. My Php code does not work, because my result is always `"01.01.1970 01:33"`.

Code:

```
    $day    = date("d",$timestamp);
    $month  = date("m",$timestamp);
    $year   = date("Y",$timestamp);
    $hour   = date("H",$timestamp);
    $minute = date("i",$timestamp);
```

Comment: Is your variable `$timestamp` a Unix timestamp?

Comment: Your question contains 2 input formats. Which one do you want to use? Your first sentence talks about format different than 2nd sentence

Comment: I don't really get your question – but looking at the php functions date() (http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and mktime() (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) and maybe also strtotime() could be a good idea.

Comment: are you using strtotime in $timestamp ?

Comment: You could save the date as string with commas in a var, then explode it with commas into an array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `strtotime(string)` function, for example `date('d', strtotime('2014-08-30'))`

Answer (score 6):

Straight from php's documentation: [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse.php)

```
<?php
print_r(date_parse("2006-12-12 10:00:00.5"));
?>
```

This will give you an array with the different parts of the date, as you asked for ("easiest way to explode").